# Inconsistency with letter case in tooltip

Tags: bug, tooltips

I noticed that most tooltip's text starts with a lowercase letter:

> [image: share]
>
> [image: flag]

But for full edit queue text begins with an uppercase letter:

> [image: edit]

It should be fixed for consistency.

Comment: The top-bar icons have tooltips with capital words as well.

Comment: Got something I want you to look at... Dangit... where'd I put that image...